# BOX API to invite external user

Tags: rest, box-api

Just am trying to use BOX API for collaboration. i just wanted to know is there any REST api call available to invite a external user.

Answer (score 1):

You just POST to https://api.box.com/2.0/collaborations   with the proper auth header for your user that is authenticated (the person doing the invitation to collaborate).   In the body of the request you would put the JSON to specify the folder and the invitee.

```
{"item": { "id": "12137", "type": "folder"}, "accessible_by": { "login": "rob@winterfell.com"}, "role": "editor"}
```

Then rob@winterfell.com will get an email telling them that they've been invited to see the appropriate folder.